# How to compare two PCAs

Tags: neural-networks, pca

I am working on a deep learning research and came across the following problem:

I have a network (let's call it `A`) that performs a certain task with X% performance, and another (say `B`) with Y% (where `X >> Y`). So `A` performs significantly better.

There is only one little difference between these two architectures but a huge performance improvement in return. I would like to compare why they perform differently. So, I compared the weights of CNN layers, etc.

After reshaping the first layer, it became (25*32) size. I got the PCA of this layer for both `A` and `B` and compared them.

Below is the PCA plot of A (good performing network) using imshow. So the values are the magnitudes of the output of PCA function. For example, the first column in the figure is the first eigenvector.

[image: pca_A]

whereas the same of the second network, `B`, is as follows:

[image: pca_B]

Then I got 10 eigenvectors of each network and normalized their variances with respect to the 10th. The resulting plot is as follows: 
(i.e., `vars = variance of each ev`, `vars = vars/vars[-1]`)

From these results, I can infer that only 2-3 eigenvectors are enough to represent `A` whereas more components needed for `B`.

`red`, `green` and `blue` are the `A` which perform well and the others `magenta` and `cyan` are `B`. (I ran `A` 3 times, and `B` 2 times)

[image: variances]

So, my question is how should I interpret these results? I mean why would a filter needing only a few eigenvectors would work better than the one requiring more.

Comment: 1) Are you only looking at the first layer? 2) How exactly are you reshaping the weights before pca; what are you treating as points and dimensions? 3) What do the axes and colors mean in your heat plots? 4) In the last plot (please label axes) it's hard to see the shape of the curves for B because they have smaller scale. Can you also plot fraction of variance explained for each component. Then A and B will have comparable scale.

Comment: @user20160. 1) other layers have similar characteristics but in the first layer, the difference is more obvious. 2) the layer's shape is (5,5,1,32). I reshape by np.reshape(A, (25,-1)). This make each 5×5 filter a column. 3) I got them using imshow. They are 25×25 PCA results in python's PCA implementation. So 25 column (principal components) 25 elements in each PC. 4) it is basically the ratio of variances of PCs with repect to 10th principal component. For example, in blue PC[0]/PC[9] = 1400.

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you mean by `fraction of variance explained for each component`. Do you mean the actual variances rather than normalized?

Comment: What a cool experiment! "fraction of variance explained" is simply $\frac{\sigma_i^2}{\sum_{j=1}^P \sigma_i^2}$ where $\sigma_i^2$ is the $i$'th eigenvalue.